# Set vb.net combobox SelectedIndex by value

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am working on a tool that saves data into a database to later retrieve it and display in the same form

I save data into the database using integer id's

In order to set combobox values I have tried the following

```
frm.statusComboBox.SelectedValue = initiativeDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(initiativeDataGridView.Columns("initiativeStatus_Id").Index()).Value
```

I understand that I am in the wrong, since I need to set the combobox selectedIndex and not the selectedValue. So I guess my main question is how do I identify the combobox index for a particular value member?

Comment: What you need to set depends on the content of the ComboBox, what is its `.DataSource`, its `ValueMember` and the relation between the `.DataSource` and the Value of a DGV's Cell. BTW, `.Index` is a property, not a method.

Comment: ID's are normally generated with and auto number field in the database. That would have nothing to do with the index in the combo box. Many times you will fill a combo from a database setting the display member to a Name field or other descriptive field and setting the value member to the ID field from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ComboBox.SelectedItem instead, but you should add the item as well, so it appears in the dropdownlist. Working with Indexes of ComboBox isn't the best idea, because they can change as you sort your ComboBox, delete or add items.